# git: fatal: index-pack failed

Tags: git, github

I tried to clone this repo few times, but get the same error. Is it because , it is huge and my connection is slow?

```
$ git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/typescript
Cloning into 'typescript'...
remote: Counting objects: 408886, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (32748/32748), done.
Receiving objects:   4% (20335/408886), 63.88 MiB | 250.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:   8% (33984/408886), 80.64 MiB | 307.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  19% (79636/408886), 143.34 MiB | 253.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  37% (154937/408886), 267.23 MiB | 329.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  45% (187088/408886), 353.31 MiB | 387.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  53% (218438/408886), 477.12 MiB | 299.00 KiB/s   
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly47.67 MiB | 367.00 KiB/s   
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

(I press ENTER few times, so the message `Receiving objects:   x%` is preserved).

I tried,

git clone --depth=1 https://git01.codeplex.com/typescript
Cloning into 'typescript'...

it never showed any progress. What other option I have to just get the latest version. (There is a download link on the site, but it is not git repo, so I can't `git pull` to update)

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try running the following:

```
git config pack.windowMemory 10m 
git config pack.packSizeLimit 20m
```

then retry the git clone.

Answer (score 5):

Its probably your Internet connection as I was able to clone the repository successfully. But anyway, if the "manual" download creates a directory structure equivalent to the git repository you can simply download it and initialize the repository there via:

> $ git init

Then run

> $ git remote add origin https://git01.codeplex.com/typescript

to add the original repository as a remote source. Finally run:

> $ git pull

to get any new data down from the original repository.

Optionally you can simply create a new empty repository and perform the steps denoted above. However, this will result again in git downloading data for you, which may break off again like it did before.

Answer (score 3):

First of all try with a high speed connection. For shared bandwidth try to clone when load is less. If still does not work,

Please use below command,

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory 256m 
git config --global pack.packSizeLimit 256m

git config --global http.postBuffer 1024M
git config --global http.maxRequestBuffer 512M
git config --global core.compression 9
```

And try to clone again.